# do I understand react virtual DOM sense correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, virtual-dom

My way of thinking:
If we want to perform something on dom element we can do it by:

```
document.getElementById("#someId").DoSomething();
document.getElementById("#someId").DoSomethingElse();
```

In that situation browser needs to search entire DOM for #someId object. Then it forgets element and searches again to perform DoSomethingElse().
To solve "forgetting and searching again" problem we can save our element as **JavaScript object**.

```
    var someElement = document.getElementById("#someId");
    someElement .DoSomething();
    someElement .DoSomethingElse();
```

Going further we can save entire group of elements or entire nodes to achieve better performance. One more step and we have **whole DOM saved as an JavaScript object** named **virtual dom**.
Is that correct way to understand purpose of virtual DOM?
Sorry for noob questions, I'm not front end developer, I'm just curious :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main point of the VirtualDOM is that, effectively, you're working on a *copy* of the real DOM. But the working with that copy is ways faster that working with the actual DOM, because it only has the thing that React actually needs, leaving specific browser issues aside.

The main problem with working with the actual DOM is that it's slow. At least, it's faster to work with that kind of copy, make your work there, and the changes have been done, then you update the actual DOM.

Yes, it sounds a bit crazy, but is faster to compute the differences between state changes and the change everything in "just one step", than making that changes with the actual DOM.

Additionally, you've used for your example just a single DOM node, but you're working on changes on DOM subtrees the thing is not that easy.

For an explanation with more detail you can take a look to this article: http://reactkungfu.com/2015/10/the-difference-between-virtual-dom-and-dom/

Comment: Additional question: Is my second snipped (with saving element as object) faster than first one? Does it actually "remember" element?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's, but we should do a benchmark to test it. Maybe it's faster to find the node twice than find it once a saving it (write operation) on a variable. Write operations tends to be more time consuming that read ones.

Comment: thanks. I'll mark your answer as accepted in the end of the day, to not scare other people who might want to add something else. Anyhow concider "acceptance" claimed :)